# Can insert HABTM data but cannot update?

Tags: php, cakephp

### What doesn't work

On **update form**, if i change checkbox values, these **habtm values don't get saved to database**.

Althought in create and update form i use the same method: `$this->Employee->save($this->data)` which should automatically handle HABTM data.

### What works

**I`v sucessfully set up HABTM Model** by following [this tutorial](http://mrphp.com.au/code/working-habtm-form-data-cakephp): Employees hasAndBelongsToMany Languages (i.e to specify which employee speaks which language).

**I can create the relations**: when creating new employee with create form, check any languages which employee knows and it sucessfully saves to database: employee goes to *employee* database table, language to *language* and the relations goes to *employee_language* table.

**On edit form, i see which checboxes i checked** while creating employee.

### What i'v found to (probably) be guilty

When evaluating what data goes to database while creating and updating employee, i'v found out that `$this->data` variable structure differs.

On create form (check 2 languages):

[image: Create form]

```
"$this->data"   Array [2]   
    Employee    Array [6]   
        name_lv John Doe    
        position_lv Computer administrator  
        enabled 0       
    Language    Array [1]   
        Language    Array [2]   
            0   1   
            1   5
```

On update form (checked additional language, so 3 languages):

[image: Update form]

```
"$this->data"   Array [1]   
    Employee    Array [8]   
        name_lv John Doe    
        position_lv Computer administrator  
        Language    Array [3]   
            0   1   
            1   5   
            2   4   
        enabled 0   
        id  68
```

Note that Languages are now accessable under `$this->data["Employee"]["Language"]` not like when creating `$this->data["Language"]`

### Workaround

If i do `$this->data["Language"] = $this->data["Employee"]["Language"];` then values get saved (yay), except that duplicate entries are present in employee_language HABTM table (oh no).

So which switch do i switch to make my checkboxes updateable?

### More details (if you will)

(model) employee.php

```
class Employee extends AppModel {
  var $name = "Employee";

  var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array (
    "Language" =>
        array(
            "className"     => "Language",
            "conditions"    => array(
                "Language.enabled" => "1"
            )
        )
  );
  ...
}
```

(model) language.php:

```
class Language extends AppModel {

  var $name = "Language";
  ...
}
```

(view) admin_create.ctp (this is create form. This snippet renders checkboxes for all available languages):

```
...
<?php  
    echo $form->input('Language',array(
        'label' => 'Speaks in languages:',
        'type' => 'select',
        'multiple' => 'checkbox',
        'options' => $languages
));  ?>
...
```

(view) admin_update.ctp (I can see which languages i checked while creating employee):

```
...
<?php  
    echo $form->input('Language',array(
        'label' => 'Speaks in languages:',
        'type' => 'select',
        'multiple' => 'checkbox',
        'options' => $languages,
        'selected' => $html->value('Employee.Language')
));  ?>
...
```

Comment: the controller code is missing. obviously there is sth wrong there. because you dont need to and you shouldnt use "selected" in your form input array.

Comment: @mark, My controller code is not missing, but you'r right - i didn't need selected property. Deleted that and everything works. Post that please as an answer so i can accept it later. But i`m still having an issue: old HABTM data doesn't get deleted when updating. But (from cakebook) "By default when saving a HasAndBelongsToMany relationship, Cake will delete all rows on the join table before saving new ones. For example if you have a Club that has 10 Children associated" Althought i set "unique" => true param in model :/ But thats probably another issue.

Comment: Janis when you EDIT what is the state of $this->data that you READ in and then set to pass to the form initially? Is it the same format as $this->data that is saved when you first CREATE?

Comment: @Janis What does your HABTM join-table structure look like?

Comment: @Leo, as i`v said, mark already provided an answer. Now my data structure AFTER EDIT is the same as when i first CREATE. However if i add `selected` property to `$form->input`, then my data structure doesn't look the same but like the second one i pasted in header "What i'v found to (probably) be guilty.".

Comment: @Farray, the table structure is fine, because i can work with it and to prevent duplicates i'm executing this before save operation: `$this->Employee->EmployeesLanguage->deleteAll(array("EmployeesLanguage.employee_id" => $id), false);`

Comment: @mark please provide your comment as an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: @Janis If I remember correctly, I had a Cake HABTM join where the table had just 2 columns (obj1_id, obj2_id) and had the same problem with not removing old HABTM data.  I added a 3rd column (id, obj1_id, obj2_id) and it fixed the problem.  Not sure if it's the same problem you're having.

Comment: @Farray thanks for the tip. My table has a PK column named id, so its probably not that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark provided an answer in comments that solves the problem:

> ... you dont need to and you shouldnt use "selected" in your form
>   input array.

Yes, when i removed "selected" property, then suddenly i was able to do UPDATE on HABTM data. 
So now my input control looks like:

```
<?php  
    echo $form->input('Language',array(
        'label' => 'Speaks in languages:',
        'type' => 'select',
        'multiple' => 'checkbox',
        'options' => $languages
));  ?>
```

Not having a way to convert comment as an answer, trying to contact @mark to post his comment as an answer, but no actions has taken, i'm answering my own question so that others can see that this question has a solution. That's what is suggested on meta:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question/1558#1558